# Is it possible to define a class based on a php variable

Tags: php, css

I want to define the body as a certain colour based upon a variable.

I have been trying things to this affect.

```
<?php

    $seperate_sitting_yes = "Yes";


    if($seperate_sitting_yes == "Yes")

{
?>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
        body {
        background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>

<?
}
?>
```

Is there a way to do this. I figured as you could use HTML in this way, maybe you could define styles like this...

Any thoughts...Thanks.

Comment: what is your question? did you try what you just wrote? cause it should work.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut It doesn't work because he closes the style tag twice.

Comment: I have tried this. it just writes "body { background-color: blue; }"

Comment: right. there is a syntax error on style tag. remove the first  `</style> ` and try again

Comment: Of course it just writes `body {background-color:blue;}`, you are setting the variable to `yes` and later you check: if the value is `yes`, make the background blue.

Comment: Silly mistake. Sorry. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @SpringheeledJack , if you found your answer , please keep marked as true to answer.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your unedited question you had a `</style>` too much, just remove the `</style>` tag and it works!!

```
<?php
        $seperate_sitting_yes = "Yes";
        if($seperate_sitting_yes == "Yes")
    {
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
 <?php
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
<?php $seperate_sitting_yes = 'Yes'; ?>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: <?= $seperate_sitting_yes == "Yes" ? "blue" : ""; ?>;
    }
</style>
```

or

```
<?php $seperate_sitting_yes = 'Yes'; ?>
<?php if($seperate_sitting_yes == "Yes") : ?>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: "blue";
    }
</style>
<?php endif ?>
```

or

```
<?php $seperate_sitting_yes = 'Yes';
    if($seperate_sitting_yes == 'Yes'){
     echo '<style type="text/css"> body {background-color: "blue";}</style>';
    }
?>
```